# faster way to translate Html themes and Demos

Tags: html, themes, translation

I bought some Html Themes and I want to translate them. I need a fast and free way to translate themes.
I tried by Poedit but it can not open the Html file!
please introduce a way to Automatic translate Html file or a free application like Poedit

Answer (score 0):

You can try using google translate. And you can do it in two ways:

1. Use their web app and upload your .html file, but first, you need to rename it to txt.

[image]

2. You can embed the Google Translate button on your web page. For more details check out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp)